# Debugging in PHP and Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

`@ini_set('log_errors','On');`
and
`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

I'm trying to create a error log file , but i'm confusing about these two.
what kind of errors will get by `log_errors` and `WP_DEBUG` ?

Comment: I know this is really old question. But hope this article help someone
https://digitecz.com/web-development/how-to-debug-wordpress-using-browsers-javascript-console/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` will log errors into the debug.log file in the wp-content directory, `@ini_set('log_errors','On');` allows you to specify the file where you want to save it. This should work for you:

```
@ini_set('log_errors', 1);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0); /* enable or disable public display of errors (use 'On' or 'Off') */
@ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/logs/your-error-file.log'); /* path to server-writable log file */
@ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ); /* the php parser to  all errors, excreportept notices.  */
```

Comment: thank you for answering but in your code you did have code like `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` then how debug will work?

Comment: WP_DEBUG_LOG is just an additional PHP constants that extend WP_DEBUG, you don't need to add it if you want to use your custom log file.

Comment: okay thank you, and i have another doubt if updating plugins , themes has any errors , this `log_errors ` will  get them?

Answer (score 2):

The `@ini_set('log_errors','On');` option sets the PHP handler to log errors. It is a general configuration option used to control script's behaviour. [More on the function here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

The `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` on the other hand is very WP specific, it is used to capture and either print to screen / write to file WP specific errors. [More on it here](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG).

**Writing to a log file**

1. PHP

PHP stores error logs in `/var/log/apache2` if PHP is an Apache2 module. Shared hosts are often store log files in your root directory `/log` subfolder.

If you have access to a php.ini file you can specify the path like this:

```
error_log = /var/log/custom-logging-script.log
```

2. WordPress

You can tell WP to log entries to a file by setting `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` . That causes all errors to also be saved to a `debug.log` log file inside the `/wp-content/` directory.

3. Alternately

If you quickly want to inspect a function or a variable then try something like this `error_log($my_error, 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");`. Its a handy function, [more details here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php).

What you use depends on your requirement and what you want to debug.